# Analyzing the singularity of $f(z)= \sin\big(\frac{1}{\cos(\frac1z)}\big)$ at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

For the function :

$$f(z)= \sin\bigg(\frac{1}{\cos(\frac1z)}\bigg)$$

the point $z=0$ is:

1)a removable singularity

2)a pole

3)an essential singularity

4)a non-isolated singularity

The answer seems to be 3)an essential singularity.

But I arrived at 1)removable singularity because when $f(z)$ has removable singularity,

$\lim\limits_{z\to0}$  $(z-z_0)$$f(z)=0$.
(Since $\lim\limits_{x\to a}$$f(x)=f(a)$.)

Can someone help me, pointing out where I had gone wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may not plug in the value in a limit unless the function is continuous. The whole point is that the function is not continuous at 0. You are trying to determine how bad this discontinuity is

Answer (score 2):

It has a non-isolated singularity at $0$, since it has a singularity at every point of the form $\frac1{\pi/2+n\pi}$ ($n\in\mathbb N$).

It is not true that $\lim_{z\to0}zf(z)=0$. Actually, this limit does not exist.

Comment: I couldn't understand how is this a non-isolated singularity. Could you please explain again? I am convinced that it is not a removable singularity. We say, for example, $f(z) = cot z$ has isolated singularity at $z_0 = n\pi$. So how is this non-isolated? Thank you.

Comment: @user517123 Because $0$ is a singularity and, as I proved, there are singularities arbitrarily close to $0$. That's what “non-isolated” mean.

Comment: What about essential singularity? Doesn't have infinitely many negative power terms in the Laurent series expansion?

Comment: @Unknownx The function $f$ has no Lauret expansion around $0$.

Comment: $\sin \left(\frac{1}{\cos \left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}\right)=\sec \left(\frac{1}{z}\right)-\frac{\sec ^3\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}{3!}+\frac{\sec ^5\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}{5!}-...\infty =\left(1+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^2}{2!}+\frac{5\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^4}{4!}+...\right)-\frac{\left(1+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^2}{2!}+\frac{5\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^4}{4!}+...\ \infty \right)^3}{3!}+...\infty $

Comment: Isn't it having infinite negative powers? please explain sir@JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: A Laurent series centered at $0$ is an infinite sum of the form $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nz^n$. Where are the $a_n$'s in what you wrote?

Comment: $\left(1+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^2}{2!}+\frac{5\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^4}{4!}+...\right)-\frac{\left(1+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^2}{2!}+\frac{5\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^4}{4!}+...\ \infty \right)^3}{3!}+...\infty$

Comment: it is in the form $\sum_{n=-\infty }^{0} z^n$. Right? what is the problem of writing like this sir?